# WCF Serialising Enums using Message Contracts

Tags: wcf, enums, serialization, messagecontract

I have some web services that use Message contracts. It's probably worth mentioning that for these services, I cannot shift to Data contracts...

One of my types specifies a property whose type happens to be an enum:

```
[SerializableAttribute()]
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
[KnownType(typeof(RiskTypeCode))]
public partial class RiskType : Lookup
{

    private RiskTypeCode codeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlElement(ElementName="code")]
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public RiskTypeCode Code
    {
        get
        {
            return this.codeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.codeField = value;
        }
    }
```

e.t.c.

My enum is defined as:

```
[Serializable()]
[DataContract]
public enum RiskTypeCode
{

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlEnumAttribute(Name = "THING1")]
    [EnumMember]
    THING1,

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlEnumAttribute(Name="THING2")]
    [EnumMember]
    THING2,

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlEnumAttribute(Name="THING3")]
    [EnumMember]
    THING3,
}
```

But when I send this across the wire, the RiskTypeCode property is not serialised - i.e. it's ommitted from the output.

What do I need to decorate my enum/property with to get it across the wire?

Comment: Hi @Kiquenet, sorry this was so long ago I don't remember how it was solved. I suspect we probably switched it for an integer, or possibly created an override for the stock serialiser.

Comment: @Kiquenet It looks useful, but I don't have the codebase anymore to verify whether this solves the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using **DataContract** and **EnumMember**, for a **MessageContract**.

```
    [DataContract(Name = "ModoConsulta")]
    public enum ModoConsulta
    {
        [EnumMember()]
        Default = 0,
        [EnumMember()]
        RequestEV= 1,
        [EnumMember()]
        Server = 2
    }

    [MessageContract]
    public class QueryAdvancedReq : QueryReq
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public DateTime? FromDate{ get; set; }

        [MessageBodyMember]
        public ModoConsulta Mode { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var str = new StringBuilder();
            str.Append(base.ToString());

            str.Append("FromDate : ");
            str.Append(FromDate== null ? "null" : FromDate.ToString());
            str.Append(", ");

            str.Append("Mode : ");
            str.Append(Mode == null ? "null" : Mode.ToString());
            str.Append(", ");

            return str.ToString();
        }

    }
```